# VS Code C++ rename symbol, skip comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I'm using VS Code v1.51.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.5. I'm trying to refactor a C++ project. When I use `Rename Symbol` on `grid` symbol, its instances in comments are to be renamed too, see the right pane on the screenshot below (preview mode). I don't want that. `Find All References` is able to skip `grid` occurrences in comments as shown in the left pane below:

[image]

Is there a way to use `Find All References` list to guide the renaming?